# Short, but not sweet

Tags: riddle

Smoking makes me blush
And smell rather strongly
I'll achieve my purpose
If you answer this wrongly

**Who am I?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are a

> herring

Smoking makes me blush

> Smoking herring turns it red.

And smell rather strongly

> Smoked herring has a strong smell.

I'll achieve my purpose if you answer this wrongly

> A red herring is a clue meant to be misleading.

Short, but not sweet

> A herring is a small fish, and it does not taste sweet!

Comment: I was literally coming here to post this.

Comment: Yes. The title is also a clue of sorts, so you may want to add that.

Answer (score 10):

You are a

> Butt

Short, but not sweet

> Pun hiding "but" in the title, also, I don't know any sweet butts.

Smoking makes me blush

> Cigarette butts have a red ember (blush) when you smoke.

And smell rather strongly

> Both smoking and butts can smell rather strong.

I'll achieve my purpose
If you answer this wrongly

> Because I have probably answered this wrong, I will be the butt of the joke.

Comment: i wanted to know what butt is...guess what i found when i googled it..;)

Comment: Well, you got the last part right (you answered this wrongly). Anyway, nice answer. :-)