# Short, but it shouldn't be sweet

Tags: word, wordplay, knowledge

Inspired by [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #41 : Short and Sweet](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6502/fortnightly-topic-challenge-41-short-and-sweet), this puzzle suddenly appeared in my head:

> "When American prefer to bring milk rather than water they will be called _____(5)."
>
> The intended answer is close to students and artists, and also the reason why this puzzle **inspired by** not **an entry of** [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #41 : Short and Sweet](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6502/fortnightly-topic-challenge-41-short-and-sweet)

**Hint 1**

> Please read carefully the description of  [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #41 : Short and Sweet](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6502/fortnightly-topic-challenge-41-short-and-sweet)

<sub>Note: This puzzle is not related to [Short, but not sweet](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/25078/short-but-not-sweet)</sub>

Comment: just to be sure; They shoot each other less?

Comment: @Jannis, if you have a good explanation, try to post it as answer ;)

Comment: Will their shoes be too big because they lactose?

Comment: @RuperMorrish And then they'll be ostracized by their peers who are lack-toes intolerant

Comment: @malioboro : I think it's quite time to give either a new clue, or the intended solution !

Answer (score 10):

*note: this answer matches the question better as it was before its last edit.*

They

> scowl

Did you know that

> Milk comes  from cows

?

Yes, that totally justifies the 'knowledge' tag. Moreover

> Water is H2O.

From there

> Remove 'H2O' from 'School' because they don't bring water anymore and you get 'scl'. Students rather bring milk, so replace 'H2O' by 'cow' into school and you get 'sccowl'. If you have seen it once, you don't need to see it twice, so you can as well remove the redundant 'c'.

Hence the answer:

> scowl

And

> A child scowling is short, but shouldn't be sweet (unless she is really too cute when she scowls).

Comment: Dear down-voter, mind to explain ?

Comment: +1 This is the best answer so far! the solution has the same approach with your answer, but you still miss the "American" part. And also I've updated my question to avoid "too broad" answer

Answer (score 8):

I think that the answer is:

> Sour
>  because the milk not kept in the fridge will go off and become sour
>  which explains the title as well - not sweet

Comment: nice answer! but not the intended answer, I hope the answer will also fit other hidden clues in the puzzle, but +1 (lrf, gur gvgyr vf n pyhr)

Comment: @malioboro If that's not the right answer, can we get some hints?

Comment: The answer is probably 5 letters long, since there's a "(5)" at the end of the clue.

Answer (score 7):

Is the answer:

> Thatcher

Because:

> Margaret Thatcher (ex UK Prime Minister) famously took English students' milk away, so she will do the same to Americans if they try it! (And as the Iron Lady, she isn't known for being sweet)

Comment: great answer! but not the intended one. How does it answer the question?  (V nqzvg guvf nafjre nafjref nyzbfg nyy pyhrf, ohg gurer vf n "jbeqcynl" gnt gurer)

Comment: I really like the answer, but it is probably 5 letters long, since there's a "(5)" at the end of the clue.

Answer (score 6):

> babies
>
>  Because if the children take more milk to the school the family will need more milk. So the Milkman has to come way more often to the families while both the children (school) and the father (work) are away. Which in the end results in many more born babies. And with the title babies are short and shouldn´t be sweet (but they are).

Comment: +1 for the last sentence, I agree with you! but this is not the intended answer :) I've updated my question to warn about the tags

Comment: The answer is probably 5 letters long, since there's a "(5)" at the end of the clue.

Comment: @Hugh yeah thats a new requirement also the text got changed so my answer is no longer fitting.

Answer (score 6):

What about

> tears

because

> inevitably, somebody clumsy will end up [crying over spilled milk](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/cry-over-spilled-milk)

Answer (score 5):

I believe the answer is

> They study a lot better

Because

> Rather than "watering down" the knowledge, they "milk it".

Comment: The answer is probably 5 letters long, since there's a "(5)" at the end of the clue.

Answer (score 4):

Another try:

> Latte

because (Thanks to @Jannis)

> Milk in coffee is called latte (American students prefer a latte) Original a latte shouldn't be sweet but in America most Latte's are sweet drinks.

Comment: The answer is probably 5 letters long, since there's a "(5)" at the end of the clue.

Comment: lbhe nafjre vf pbeerpg, naq lbh nyfb fbyirq gur pyhr va gur gvgyr, ohg V'yy npprcg hagvy lbh nafjre nyy gur pyhrf

Comment: @malioboro Qbrf vg unir fbzrguvat gb qb jvgu orvat yngr? (ab gvzr gb nqq zvyx gb pbssrr va gur zbeavat sbe rknzcyr)

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer?

> I'm pretty sure it has something to do with coffee and keep coming back to [**crema**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crema) somehow... Maybe because the word contains MA (Master of Arts). And I'm not sure about this, but I think it's also a term for an Americano with milk? All the other clues seem to point to coffee\espresso, anyway (a short drink? shouldn't be sweet? and a link to the Meta post that mentions coffee?) but nothing is falling neatly into place so far. :( Hope this helps someone find the real answer!

Another farfetched solution was:

> *allas* [as in All A's (students) which sounds like au-lait's (with milk)], but that doesn't really work.

Comment: How about rot13[ynggr]? That's five letters, and has milk instead of water...

Comment: @jafe Thought of that (and also zbpun and zbxnf), but just can't see how it *all* fits.

Comment: Na Nzrevpnab vf rfcerffb jvgu jngre. Oevat zvyx vafgrnq bs jngre, lbh trg rfcerffb jvgu zvyx. V.r. n ynggr?

Comment: @jafe Jung, naq fghqragf naq negvfgf whfg yvxr gurz? Dunno, could be. It just doesn't really seem like wordplay.

Comment: Hmm, fair point. Not sure...

Comment: @jafe npghnyyl lbhe thrff vf pbeerpg! gur ernfbavat vf nyfb pbeerpg, nobhg gur fghqrag orpnhfr vg vf pybfr gb "yngr" naq nobhg gur negvfg lbh cebonoyl nyernql xarj vg

Comment: Fb... guvf vf gur nafjre? Orpnhfr V'z phevbhf.

Answer (score 3):

> Salty ...

because

> idk, I'm guessing because of @rhsquared answer
>  The milk contains calcium (good for bones) in a ionbinding -> making a salt
>  \_(°.°)_/

Comment: nice answer! which is fit "knowledge" tag, but sorry, not the intended answer, what happens with "American student" part ;)